# Retrieve a list of available locations from Azure - Python SDK

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, sdk, cloud

I'd like to save a list of available locations for my subscription to Azure. I have this so far:

```
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient


class ProviderAzure(CloudProviderAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, client_id, access_secret_key, tenant, subscription_id, location):
        super(ProviderAzure, self).__init__()

        self.credentials = [subscription_id,
                            ServicePrincipalCredentials(
                                client_id=client_id,
                                secret=access_secret_key,
                                tenant=tenant)]

        self.location = location
        self.subscription_id = subscription_id
        self.subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(self.credentials)

    def list_available_locations(self):
        locations = self.subscription_client.subscriptions.list_locations(self.subscription_id)
        for location in locations:
            print(location.name)
```

But when I run list_available_locations(), I get this output:

```
     63         session = request.context.session
     64         try:
---> 65             self._creds.signed_session(session)
     66         except TypeError: # Credentials does not support session injection
     67             _LOGGER.warning("Your credentials class does not support session injection. Performance will not be at the maximu
m.")


AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'signed_session'
```

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the list? I'm using python2.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials object you pass to `SubscriptionClient` is invalid, you pass a list with two elements: subscription_id + credentials class. The SubscriptionClient only takes the credentials class by design (since it's a subscription client it doesn't take a subscription as input)

```
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient


class ProviderAzure(CloudProviderAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, client_id, access_secret_key, tenant, subscription_id, location):
        super(ProviderAzure, self).__init__()

        self.credentials =  ServicePrincipalCredentials(
                                client_id=client_id,
                                secret=access_secret_key,
                                tenant=tenant)

        self.location = location
        self.subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(self.credentials)

    def list_available_locations(self):
        locations = self.subscription_client.subscriptions.list_locations(self.subscription_id)
        for location in locations:
            print(location.name)
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!